# How to heat a bathtub when the water heater isn't doing enough?

Tags: water-heater, bathtub, hot-water

I have a big tub and a small water heater.  I live in an apartment so there's not much I can do about that right now.  I've looked into immersion heaters and from what I can tell they aren't meant for bathtubs (don't produce enough energy), and/or take a long time to heat the water.

What are alternatives that I can combine with the under-powered water heater to get my tub water hot?

Comment: What is the tub made of? A solution for cast iron, e.g. bonding a heating mat to the outside, might not work for fiberglass. What is the volume? How much power do you have available, e.g. one 120V 15A receptacle or 40A at 240V? Gas? How hot is the water when the tub is filled and how hot do you want it?  A 1500W heater is going to take a while to raise 50 gallons of water from 60°F to 105°F.

Comment: Have you tried turning the thermostat up on the water heater?

Comment: Stumbled over [Water Heating Calculator for Time, Energy, and Power](https://bloglocation.com/art/water-heating-calculator-for-time-energy-power) which may provide a reality check. [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) just wasn't cooperating.

Comment: Boil a lot of water?

Comment: Have you slowed the flow as far as it will go? You normally have to tweak them summer/winter so you don't scald yourself in summer & freeze in winter. If it's still too cool at its slowest, the fix might be as simple as a new diaphragm - under a tenner, (& legal to DIY even in the UK as you're not touching the gas side) but if it's not your heater let someone else do that.

Answer (score 2):

What about good-ol-fashioned heating or even boiling water on the stove? You'll need a thermometer to ensure your water doesn't go over 120 degrees.

When I was working on my water heater recently, I used spare aquarium heaters to heat up 5 gallon buckets. You can buy up to 300w on those....some aquarists guide will say what wattage heater for say, a 60 gallon or a 100 gallon tank. You can calculate the number of gallons you intend to heat in the tub before you buy any heater.

Comment: Is the 120 degree limit just for my own safety?

Answer (score 1):

Many modern bathtub faucets have temperature limiters.

[image]

Perhaps yours is set too low.  If so, it can be adjusted higher.

Comment: As long as the cold tap is off the water should be as hot at it would get from the water heater anyway right?

Comment: If you have separate taps for hot and cold then yes.

Answer (score 1):

My bathroom is like a lot of homes and is on an outside wall and is sitting on top of the floor, or subfloor, I haven't looked that closely. My tub is cast iron and gets ice cold even when it's not freezing outside. I was thinking of removing enough flooring to uncover the bottom of the tub and place electric coils underneath but not actually touching the tub. They would be inside a metal enclosure and placed to the rear of the tub since the front, closest to the faucet would heat up quickly from the hot water directed onto the tub surface. This is just an idea and I haven't put it to test yet, but I will build a mock-up on a small scale to see if it is worth making one on a large scale. As soon as I have finished my model, I will provide details.